# JOptionPane will not display QUESTION_MESSAGE icon

Tags: java, joptionpane

When I specify `QUESTION_MESSAGE` for the `Icon` parameter for the `JOptionPane` input-dialog, the window displays a Java icon instead of the expected question-mark icon. The correct icons are shown if I specify `WARNING_MESSAGE` or `ERROR_MESSAGE` instead. Why is this?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WindowTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            null, "Skriv in namn", "Namnet", 
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Clarified title, grammar corrections, code-formatting

Comment: It works ok for me (it displays a question-mark icon).

Comment: What happens if you try this:  String name = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Skriv in namn", "Namnet", 0, UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.questionIcon"), null, null);